# I get a syntax error with an INSERT function with Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I try to write an insert function in Postgres, but always get the error that I have a syntax error on line 7.

```
CREATE FUNCTION "Portfolio"."Einfuegen"(IN "idIN" integer, IN "bildIN" bigint, IN "dokumenteIN" 
text[])
RETURNS SETOF "Portfolio"."Namen"
LANGUAGE 'sql'

AS $BODY$
BEGIN
  
  INSERT INTO Portfolio.Namen (_id,dokumente,bild) VALUES (idIN,dokumenteIN,bildIN);
END;
$BODY$;

ALTER FUNCTION "Portfolio"."Einfuegen"(integer, bigint, text[])
OWNER TO postgres;
```

Comment: You should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Answer (score 0):

A `language sql` function may not use a `begin  ... end;` block. Additionally: your function is declared as `returns setof` but doesn't return anything.

And once you start using the stupid double quotes around identifiers (and parameters) you have **always** use them:

So it should look like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION "Portfolio"."Einfuegen"(IN "idIN" integer, IN "bildIN" bigint, IN "dokumenteIN" text[])
  RETURNS SETOF "Portfolio"."Namen"
  LANGUAGE sql
AS 
$BODY$
  INSERT INTO "Portfolio"."Namen"(_id,dokumente,bild) 
  VALUES ("idIN", "dokumenteIN", "bildIN") --<< you have to use the quotes here as well
  returning *; -- return the newly inserted row
END;
$BODY$;
```

---

I would strongly [suggest](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names) you do not use quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble in the long run than their are worth it.